# How do I use less for function, and merge the plots?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would visualize datas from txt.
Formatting, and indexing is running well, and the code is working, but how do I make it easier, or use less for function?
I'm absolute beginner, this is my first project.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

with open('Gorbe_2.txt') as f:
    (content) = f.read().split()
    report = {"Distance": content[0::6],
              "Sensor output": content[1::6],
              "Sensor output[V]": content[2::6],
              "Vcc[V]": content[3::6],
              "Lower Curve[V%]": content[4::6],
              "Upper Curve[V%]": content[5::6]}

A = report["Distance"]
B = [float(i) for i in A]

C = report["Sensor output"]
D = [float(i) for i in C]

E = report["Sensor output[V]"]
F = [float(i) for i in E]

G = report["Vcc[V]"]
H = [float(i) for i in G]

I = report["Lower Curve[V%]"]
J = [float(i) for i in I]

K = report["Upper Curve[V%]"]
L = [float(i) for i in K]

Dis = np.array(B)
So = np.array(D)
SoV = np.array(F)
VCC = np.array(H)
L_C = np.array(J)
U_C = np.array(L)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 6))

ax.set(xlabel='Distance', ylabel='voltage (V)')
ax.grid()

plt.plot(Dis, So, 'g')
plt.plot(Dis, U_C, 'r--')
plt.plot(Dis, L_C, 'r--')

plt.show()
```

I try to do it smoother or shorter, and use less 'for' function but I need few tricks.

Comment: Check out [codereview.se].

Comment: There's nothing fundamentally wrong with this.  You can combine each `A = report[...]` / `B = [float(i) for i kn K` / `Dis = np.array(B)` set into one line, but I'm not sure that aids the readability.

Comment: Can you post what the txt file looks like ?

Comment: This is the first row from text   "-12.000 74.194 3.487 4.699 71.003 75.849".   Continues more than 1000 rows

Comment: please post sample input data in the question section. Also please post expected answer